# WPF, SQLite and Lazy Loading

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, sqlite, lazy-loading

I'm working on a WPF app with SQLite database for local data storage.
I installed *EntityFramework 6.1.3* and *System.Data.SQLite 1.0.105.1* from NuGet and properly configured App.config file.

These are my entities

```
public class Event
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Guid ContractId { get; set; }
    public virtual Contract Contract { get; set; }
}

public class Contract
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    [Required]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

When I execute the following code, I get a *System.NullReferenceException* exception, and if I put a breakpoing, I can see that *Contract* within *e1* is null.

```
using (SqliteDbContext ctx = new SqliteDbContext())
{
    var e1 = ctx.Events.FirstOrDefault();

    MessageBox.Show(e1.Contract.Id.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use eager loading to load the related entity:

```
using (SqliteDbContext ctx = new SqliteDbContext())
{
    var e1 = ctx.Events.Include(x => x.Contract).FirstOrDefault();
    MessageBox.Show(e1.Contract.Id.ToString());
}
```

**Entity Framework Loading Related Entities:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Eager loading works fine, but I want to use Lazy loading...

Comment: Apparently this is not supported for SQLite unless you have disabled it explicitly: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/lazy-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx. Also note that EF7 does not support lazy Loading of navigation properties: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data. So eager loading is probably your only choice here.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not supported for SQlite?
From this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458395/entity-framework-sqlite-and-lazy-loading
seems that SQLite supports it.

Comment: For the benefit of anyone else reading this, lazy loading seems to be working fine for me, you just gotta remember to make the members virtual so that EF can proxy them.